# Number of windows opened by selenium Web Driver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, collections

I want to get the number of instances open by selenium web driver. i have tried below snippet but interviewer was not agree. is any other way to get number of open windows by Web driver?

```
driver.getWindowHandles().size();
```

Answer (score 1):

The below code might help to count the open window instances

```
Set<String> handle= driver.getWindowHandles();
int i = 0;
for(String set : handle)
{
driver.switchTo().window(set);
i = i++;
}
System.out.println(i);
```